# Horizontally align \vdots with equal signs in aligned environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

I have a number of equations aligned at the equal sign. I insert a line containing just `\vdots` to indicate a bunch of steps and then equations again. How I can make the `\vdots` align with the equal signs?
[image]
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{twoopt}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[range-units = single]{siunitx}


\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\der}{\operatorname{d\!}{}}\renewcommand{\dfrac}[2]{\frac{\der #1}{\der #2}}
\newcommand{\pdfrac}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\sdots}{\makebox[1em][c]{.\hfil.\hfil.}\thinspace}
\newcommandtwoopt{\spint}[2][x][3]{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{\num{3}}} \! \der^#2#1 \,}
\newcommandtwoopt{\spiint}[2][x][y]{\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{\num{3}}} \! \der^{\num{3}}#1 \der^{\num{3}}#2 \,}
\newcommand{\moint}[1][p]{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{\num{3}}} \! \frac{\der^{\num{3}}#1}{\(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}}} \,}
\newcommand{\vnabla}{\vec{\nabla}}
\renewcommand{\(}{\left(}
\renewcommand{\)}{\right)}
\renewcommand{\[}{\left[}
\renewcommand{\]}{\right]}
\let\phi\varphi
\newcommandtwoopt{\nfrac}[2][1][2]{\frac{\num{#1}}{\num{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P^\mu |\vec{p}_{\num{1}},\sdots,\vec{p}_n\rangle
&= P^\mu\underbrace{\sqrt{\num{2}E_{\vec{p}_{\num{1}}}} \cdot\sdots\cdot \sqrt{\num{2}E_{\vec{p}_n}}}_{\alpha} \, a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_{\num{1}}\) \sdots a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_n\) |\num{0}\rangle \\
&= \alpha  \,a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_{\num{1}}\) \(p_{\num{1}}^\mu + P^\mu\) a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_{\num{2}}\) \sdots a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_n\) |\num{0}\rangle \\
&= \alpha  \,a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_{\num{1}}\)a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_{\num{2}}\) \[p_{\num{1}}^\mu + p_{\num{2}}^\mu +
P^\mu\] a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_{\num{3}}\) \sdots a^\dagger\(\vec{p}_n\) |\num{0}\rangle \\
&\vdots \\
&=
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very brave code:-) `\renewcommand{\(}{\left(}
\renewcommand{\)}{\right)}
\renewcommand{\[}{\left[}
\renewcommand{\]}{\right]}`

Comment: I take that as a compliment. I've found it to work very well so far. Are there known issues with this?

Comment: `\(` and `\[` are the standard latex commands to enter math mode, so if code using your redefinitions and code assuming the standard definitions ever mix then the document will be very broken.

Comment: try for example `\begin{displaymath}a=b\end{displaymath}` with and without the redefinitions

Comment: I don't think I understand. How can they mix up if I redefined the commands. The old ones are overwritten, no?

Comment: If you use `displaymath` or algorithmic package or bliondtex package or xscak package or akk package or rcs package (just a few that came up on a search of `\(` then your redefinitions will make the package commands fail as they use `\(` or `\[` to get in to math mode and you have redefined them. redefining  core commands of the latex language is bound to break a lot of packages.

Comment: I see. So it's not that brave to redefine these commands if you know about the accompanying restrictions, which I now do, thanks to you.

Comment: So should I delete this question, or leave it here to make the answer in the other question more easily discoverable? After all, my quick search didn't turn it up.

Comment: leave it: it's fine to leave duplicates once they are marked as such